# Why Bootloader needs to Support File System?

Tags: bootloader, bios

I Need to Know, why is it so, that boot loader needs to support The File system. According to what I've read. The Code in the storage Device needs to be in the first 512 bytes & with AA55  signature at its end, & has to loaded into the RAM & processor executes it. Why is it required for the boot loader to support the file system ?

Answer (score 0):

Because for most boot loaders, the first 512 bytes isn't enough.

Also, configuration files for the bootloader are stored in one of the file systems.

You can find more information on this on [Wikipedia's grub boot loader article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB#GRUB_version_1_.28GRUB_legacy.29).

Answer (score 0):

The primary job of a boot-loader is to fetch the main program from either some persistent storage medium (hard-disk or flash memory) or over the network, load it to memory (think SDRAM) and then pass control to it.

If you plan to have a boot-loader that does not do any of these then you could skip adding the code for having the boot-loader understand how file-systems work. However, if the boot-loader is going to load the program from any storage device then it needs to understand the basic layout of the filesystem used for formatting the device and stick to the defined protocol for loading something from the disk.

Similarly, if the boot-loader needs to load anything over network then it needs to have some code for the network stack to be able to communicate with anything on the network.